# Using Athena SQL with regex

Tags: sql, amazon-athena

I'm using DbVisualizer to connect to an athena instance. I have a working query:

```
SELECT device, description, id, size, date FROM test.database WHERE month = '01'
and device not like '%link%'
and device not like '%Link%'
and device not like '%LINK%'
and id not like '%abc%'
and id not like '%Abc%'
and id not like '%ABC%'
group by device, description, id, size, date order by month desc
```

What I would like to do is clean it up and catch the cases using regex. I'm pretty sure  `/link.*/ig` and `/abc.*/ig` would catch the case changes it but I don't know how to insert it in. I could not get `"input.regex" =` to work either.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You may use `REGEXP_LIKE` here:

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT device, description, id, size, date
FROM test.database
WHERE
    month = '01' AND
    NOT REGEXP_LIKE(device, '[lL]ink|LINK') AND
    NOT REGEXP_LIKE(device, '[aA]bc|ABC')
ORDER BY
    month DESC;
```

Note that your `GROUP BY` logic can also just be represented by a distinct select, for which I have opted above.

Comment: This works great,and I learned something about using DISTINCT

Answer (score 5):

Assuming you want to just ignore case, you could probably simplify the suggestion from Tim Biegeleisen by writing:

```
SELECT DISTINCT device, description, id, size, date
FROM test.database
WHERE
    month = '01' AND
    NOT REGEXP_LIKE(device, '(?i)link|abc') 
ORDER BY
    month DESC;
```